# What is the significance of Dhoti in life of a Hindu male?

Tags: culture, dress

Does Dhoti have any Hindu religious association or is it simply ancient Indian dress for males?
Is there any reference in shastras or elsewhere that a hindu male when doing puja or other religious activities ought to dress in Dhoti and such clothing ?

Comment: This dress is mentioned in agamas, the design is to allow for prana flow.

Comment: @Akhil, can you please quote here from the agamas